# How make some triggers in one?

Tags: mysql, sql

**Trigger 1:**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `Trigger 1` AFTER INSERT ON `Likes`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
UPDATE News SET 
`CountUpLikes` = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Likes` WHERE `NewsIdn` = OLD.`NewsIdn` AND `Type` = 'up'),
`CountDownLikes` = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM `Likes` WHERE `NewsIdn` = OLD.`NewsIdn` AND `Type` = 'down'),
`CountFavorites` = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Likes` WHERE `NewsIdn` = OLD.`NewsIdn` AND `IsFavorite` = 'yes') c;
END
```

**Trigger 2:**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `Trigger 1` AFTER UPDATE ON `Likes`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
UPDATE News SET 
`CountUpLikes` = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Likes` WHERE `NewsIdn` = OLD.`NewsIdn` AND `Type` = 'up'),
`CountDownLikes` = (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM `Likes` WHERE `NewsIdn` = OLD.`NewsIdn` AND `Type` = 'down'),
`CountFavorites` = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Likes` WHERE `NewsIdn` = OLD.`NewsIdn` AND `IsFavorite` = 'yes') c;
END
```

Tell me please how make two triggers in one?

For example can i make

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Trigger full` AFTER UPDATE OR INSERT ON `Likes`
```

or no ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use 1 trigger instead some triggers. Mysql does not allow for multiple events on the same trigger.